# How Can I Get My Dynamic IP Address of My Android Device

Tags: android, dynamic, ip-address

I give the permission of accessing Internet in android manifest file as below.
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

and following code will written in simple application.

```
package com.GetIP;


import java.net.InetAddress;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IPAddress extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             try
                {
                    InetAddress ownIP=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                    //System.out.println("IP of my Android := "+ownIP.getHostAddress());

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ownIP.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Exception caught ="+e.getMessage());
                    }
        }
    });
}
```

}

the above code give out put as localhost/127.0.0.1 but its a default ip address but i want dynamic ip address of my device to used in chatting application.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code will give you your local ip address:

```
public static String getLocalIpAddressString() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }
            }   
        }
    }catch (SocketException ex) {
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: This code will given me the IPv6 address but i want it in IPv4 address. Please suggest me java code for converting IPv6 to IPv4 address.

Comment: @jay have you got the solution for the same, Please share if you got.

Comment: InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address might be of use?

Comment: @pyus13: I don't  get any solution but i had changed the way of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of IP addresses attached to your device using the following code.

```
public static List<String> getLocalIpAddress() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    list.add(inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
    }
    return list;
}
```